# Is it possible to fetch data from an opcua server using AngularJS?

Tags: php, angularjs

I intend to change an application built in labVIEW platform to a web app using AngularJS. For all required features such as getting data from database, user authentication with LDAP, I have options, but I could not find a solution on how to connect to an opcua server using AngularJS and/or PHP. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.